# why Joomla 3.0.1 is slow - both back end and front end

Tags: joomla-3.x

Back-end is very slow. I just installed J3.0.1 core - no extensions, no templates, no anything extra - just a raw naked Joomla. ... And the back-end is annoyingly slow. Even, the front end is not fast J2.5 is much faster even with dozen of heavy 3rd-party components installed.

Is there anybody else, who is experiencing the same (or I have to look for the reason somewhere else)?

Comment: Is this the same system you are running 2.5 on?

Answer (score 2):

Latest version of Joomla is **3.3.6.** Provided you have no other extensions installed, try **updating to the latest** one.

However, I would like to mention some of the techniques you can apply to speed-up your Joomla site.

1. Enable Joomla **Caching**.

Detail information about caching is described [here](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/joomla/joomla-speed.htm#cache).

2. Enable Gzip **Compression**.

On admin menu go to Site > Global Configuration > Server tab, and switch the Gzip Page Compression to **YES** option.

3. Optimization of **Media** files.

Try using **minified versions** of JS and CSS files. And for images, don’t try to upload **big scale pictures**, **re-size** them before uploading.

And the last part I want to mention is, choose a **good web host** by doing a little research.